# Smaller-than-others favicon in Firefox for Stack Exchange sites

Tags: bug, design, firefox, favicon

As the title says, I find small-ish the favicon of Stack Overflow in the bookmarks bar on the latest Firefox (57). Is this intended?

[image: Firefox bookmarks bar screenshot]

Edit: Confirmed, the same happens in Server Fault (and probably most SE sites).

Comment: Looks like they simply didn't use the whole space when creating the icon, leaving large padding. No idea if bug or on purpose, though.